# User Login & Sessions :Safe or Not

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

DB table: login_info

```
--------------------------------------
| login      |  passwd    |  company |
--------------------------------------
|company1    |  passmd5   | company1 |
--------------------------------------
|company2    |  passmd5   | company2 |
--------------------------------------
|company3    |  passmd5   | company3 |
--------------------------------------
```

once login matches, the login name and company name is saved in a session variable.

```
$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $log['login']; //where $log is the mysql_fetch_assoc result array
$_SESSION['log_company_id'] = $log['company'];
```

Then using the stored company name in the session variable, the company details are loaded from a company specific db.
I am not relying on cookies for storing this information. 
Is this method safe? Should I do something else? Any other security measures that I should know of?

Comment: Not to worry, I misread your post, this is normal way to accomplish login systems and user management although there are a few things should watch out for such as **Session Hijacking**. Google it :)

Comment: @Gumbo: using only a Session variable to check for login status.

Comment: thats good way but you can use encrypted value, if you are more conscious about safety .

Comment: @JapanPro, you don't really need to use an excerpted value, if they a hacker had access to your session files or can write server side then that's the least of your worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of storing the loginid in a variable and just "assuming" that its the same person you might want to store the session as a record in a database. then have the id of this record in the session variable.

That way you can store the user's IP address in the database and when you check the session you can check the ip address against the session in the database - this will eliminate session hijacking and will add more security.